# Removing Columns from Parse API Call

Tags: parse-platform

I am making an API call to pull columns from our parse dashboard. I am using the keys parameter to limit the call to only bringing in a couple fields. However, no matter what I set the keys parameter to, it automatically brings in the "createdAt" and "updatedAt" fields no matter what. Is there anyway to remove or filter out those 2 fields entirely?

This is the http request that I am currently using:

https://our-parse-server.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/our-table?limit=5000&keys=column1,column2

Thanks!

Comment: These are added by default along with `objectID` and `ACL`. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/86e9351cd0810d441a36214c7ae17dfbbd093b28/src/Controllers/SchemaController.js#L460 - You could create a cloud function to return only the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are *sent by default* by *Parse* when fetching an object even if the query is done with the **select** method http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.2.1/Parse.Query.html#select and those attribute names are not passed in as parameters.

One possible solution would be to create a cloud function and customize the data to be returned.